# What is the difference between last_user_update and modify_date?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to figure out when a table has been amended. Using the 2 different sets of code below, I get 2 different answers:

```
Select * 
from sys.tables 
where name = 'AN_StockChecks_000_Specs_010_StockChecks_010_PlantStockCheckSettings'
```

Output:

```
modify_date
-----------------------
2015-12-07 15:40:58.557
```

Approach #2:

```
SELECT 
    OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS DatabaseName, last_user_update, *
FROM 
    sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE 
    database_id = DB_ID( 'IESA_DWHS')
    AND ID = OBJECT_ID('AN_StockChecks_000_Specs_010_StockChecks_010_PlantStockCheckSettings')
```

Output:

```
last_user_update
-----------------------
2015-12-10 09:25:43.290
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396750/what-exactly-are-createdate-and-modifydate-in-sys-objects

Comment: and this - http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12749/finding-the-last-time-a-table-was-updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `modify_date` from `sys.tables` is the date when the table **structure** was last modified - when you last added or dropped a column, or changed a column's properties.

Or as SQL Server Books Online puts it:

> **modify_date**
>   Date the object was last modified by using an **ALTER** statement. If the object is a table or a view, modify_date also changes when a clustered index on the table or view is created or altered.

It has nothing to do with data operations on that table.